# How to iterate through directories of zip files and locate & append files without a .zip extension

Tags: files, terminal, directory, zip

I have a directory of sub-directories that contain sub-directories which are supposed to be compressed archive files. Structure is illustrated below

```
ParentDirectory
|-SubDirectoryA
 |-File Mr X.zip
 |-File Mr. X
|-SubDirectoryB
 |-File Mrs X
 |-File Mrs. L.T.D X
```

I am trying to update the files that do not have the .zip extension, below is the expected result

```
ParentDirectory
|-SubDirectoryA
 |-File Mr X.zip
 |-File Mr. X.zip
|-SubDirectoryB
 |-File Mrs X.zip
 |-File Mrs. L.T.D X.zip
```

I have the current code, but unsure of how to append an extension. I also realise that the below code is looking for occurrences of a period in the prefix variable, but some file names have periods in them. Below is my attempt

```
for dir in */; do
    (cd "$dir" && for fname in *.*; do
         prefix=${fname%.*}
        [ ! -f "$fname" ] || [ -f "$prefix.zip" ] && continue
         mv -- "$fname" "${fname%}.zip"  
    done)
done
```

Comment: Why not use `find`? Something like (untested) `find -type f -a ! -name "*.zip" -exec mv {} {}.zip \;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to filter out files already zipped.

```
re="*.zip"

for dir in */; do
    (cd "$dir" && for fname in *; do
         case "${fname}" in
             $re)
                 continue
             ;;
             *)
                 mv -- "$fname" "${fname%}.zip"
             ;;
         esac
    done)
done
```